# Cut a circular hole in a curved surface (using snap to face)

Tags: modeling

I'm following along some tutorials from CGcookie and one way they describe for cutting a circle out of a curved surface is to shrink-wrap a circular mesh to the surface and then join the circle to the rest of the mesh. However, the author also states that this can be done with the "snap to face" tool in Blender, instead of using the shrink-wrap modifier. 
How can this he done with the "snap to face" tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the "use_snap_project" feature:

[image]

If you turn that on, while snapping is enabled you'll get all selected components projecting onto other objects.

Comment: yup.. that worked. Thanks :D 
It's a bit tricky to work with though. You have to make sure your mouse is hovering over the target object AND the transform handle for the mesh you're going to snap. Then, just clicking and releasing on the transform handle (click and release, no need to drag anything) will make the mesh "project" onto the target mesh.